# Intel OpenVINO: Error Verifying Installation

Tags: windows, intel, openvino

I'm new to Intel OpenVINO, I've downloaded the Installer and Followed their Installation Guide: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2019_R3.1/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html

Note that I'm Using Windows 10 with Intel processor machine,

I followed all the steps and everything went smoothly, until the part that says verify the installation by 
Running a demo file that was implemented with the installation, When I ran that file I got error says:

```
`[ ERROR ] Failed to find reference implementation for `377` Layer with `Quantize` Type on constant propagation
Error`
```

And I'm not sure what does this mean at all, So I tried to ask for help.

I asked at their Slack community, but no answer yet, So I thought about asking here,

Here is my Command Prompt that shows what I did:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.914]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\hreda>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\bin\

C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\bin>setupvars.bat
Python 3.6.0
ECHO is off.
PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\accuracy_checker;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\python\python3.6;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\python\python3;
[setupvars.bat] OpenVINO environment initialized

C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\bin>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\model_optimizer\install_prerequisites

C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\model_optimizer\install_prerequisites>install_prerequisites.bat
Python 3.6.0
ECHO is off.
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mxnet<=1.3.1,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx<2.4,>=1.11 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.4)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf==3.6.1 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 5)) (3.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: onnx>=1.1.2 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml>=0.5.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 7)) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.33.6)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.8 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.1.8)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.2.2 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: graphviz<0.9.0,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from mxnet<=1.3.1,>=1.0.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from mxnet<=1.3.1,>=1.0.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from networkx<2.4,>=1.11->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 3)) (4.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\hreda\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from protobuf==3.6.1->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 5)) (28.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.2.1 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from onnx>=1.1.2->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 6)) (3.7.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet<=1.3.1,>=1.0.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet<=1.3.1,>=1.0.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 2)) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet<=1.3.1,>=1.0.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet<=1.3.1,>=1.0.0->-r ..\requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.4)
*****************************************************************************************
Warning: please expect that Model Optimizer conversion might be slow.
You can boost conversion speed by installing protobuf-*.egg located in the
"model-optimizer\install_prerequisites" folder or building protobuf library from sources.
For more information please refer to Model Optimizer FAQ, question #80.

C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\model_optimizer\install_prerequisites>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\

C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo>demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.bat
target_precision = FP16
Python 3.6.0
ECHO is off.
PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\accuracy_checker;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\python\python3.6;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\python\python3;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\accuracy_checker;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\python\python3.6;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\python\python3;
[setupvars.bat] OpenVINO environment initialized
INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino
Python 3.6.0
ECHO is off.
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from -r C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\\..\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\requirements.in (line 1)) (5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from -r C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\\..\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\requirements.in (line 2)) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests->-r C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\\..\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\requirements.in (line 2)) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests->-r C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\\..\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\requirements.in (line 2)) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests->-r C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\\..\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\requirements.in (line 2)) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\hreda\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests->-r C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\\..\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\requirements.in (line 2)) (2.6)
Download public squeezenet1.1 model
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\downloader.py" --name squeezenet1.1 --output_dir C:\Users\hreda\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\models --cache_dir C:\Users\hreda\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\cache
################|| Downloading models ||################

========== Retrieving C:\Users\hreda\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\models\public\squeezenet1.1\squeezenet1.1.prototxt from the cache

========== Retrieving C:\Users\hreda\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\models\public\squeezenet1.1\squeezenet1.1.caffemodel from the cache

################|| Post-processing ||################

========== Replacing text in C:\Users\hreda\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\models\public\squeezenet1.1\squeezenet1.1.prototxt
squeezenet1.1 model downloading completed

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

Target folder C:\Users\hreda\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\ir\public\squeezenet1.1\FP16 already exists. Skipping IR generation with Model Optimizer.
If you want to convert a model again, remove the entire C:\Users\hreda\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\ir\public\squeezenet1.1\FP16 folder.

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

###############|| Generate VS solution for Inference Engine samples using cmake ||###############


Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
Creating Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 files in C:\Users\hreda\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\inference_engine_samples_build...
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.17763.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28314.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28314.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check size of __int32
-- Check size of __int32 - done
-- Found InferenceEngine: C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/Release/inference_engine.lib (Required is at least version "2.1")
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPUID_INFO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPUID_INFO - Success
-- Host CPU features:
--   3DNOW not supported
--   3DNOWEXT not supported
--   ABM not supported
--   ADX supported
--   AES supported
--   AVX supported
--   AVX2 supported
--   AVX512CD not supported
--   AVX512F not supported
--   AVX512ER not supported
--   AVX512PF not supported
--   BMI1 supported
--   BMI2 supported
--   CLFSH supported
--   CMPXCHG16B supported
--   CX8 supported
--   ERMS supported
--   F16C supported
--   FMA supported
--   FSGSBASE supported
--   FXSR supported
--   HLE not supported
--   INVPCID supported
--   LAHF supported
--   LZCNT supported
--   MMX supported
--   MMXEXT not supported
--   MONITOR supported
--   MOVBE supported
--   MSR supported
--   OSXSAVE supported
--   PCLMULQDQ supported
--   POPCNT supported
--   PREFETCHWT1 not supported
--   RDRAND supported
--   RDSEED supported
--   RDTSCP supported
--   RTM not supported
--   SEP supported
--   SHA not supported
--   SSE supported
--   SSE2 supported
--   SSE3 supported
--   SSE4.1 supported
--   SSE4.2 supported
--   SSE4a not supported
--   SSSE3 supported
--   SYSCALL supported
--   TBM not supported
--   XOP not supported
--   XSAVE supported
-- TBB include: C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/tbb/include
-- TBB Release lib: C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/Release/tbb.lib
-- TBB Debug lib: C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/Debug/tbb_debug.lib
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/hreda/Documents/Intel/OpenVINO/inference_engine_samples_build

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

###############|| Build Inference Engine samples using MS Visual Studio (MSBuild.exe) ||###############


Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" Samples.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:classification_sample_async /clp:ErrorsOnly /m
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

###############|| Run Inference Engine classification sample ||###############


Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
        1 file(s) copied.
classification_sample_async.exe -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\\car.png" -m "C:\Users\hreda\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\ir\public\squeezenet1.1\FP16\squeezenet1.1.xml" -d CPU
[ INFO ] InferenceEngine:
        API version ............ 2.1
        Build .................. 32974
        Description ....... API
[ INFO ] Parsing input parameters
[ INFO ] Parsing input parameters
[ INFO ] Files were added: 1
[ INFO ]     C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\\car.png
[ INFO ] Creating Inference Engine
        CPU
        MKLDNNPlugin version ......... 2.1
        Build ........... 32974

[ INFO ] Loading network files
[ INFO ] Preparing input blobs
[ WARNING ] Image is resized from (787, 259) to (224, 224)
[ INFO ] Batch size is 1
[ INFO ] Loading model to the device
[ ERROR ] Failed to find reference implementation for `377` Layer with `Quantize` Type on constant propagation
Error
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I converted a valid ONNX model to OpenVino's IR using their model optimizer, but ran into similar problems while trying to use my .xml and .bin files with their inference engine. In my case, the error was `Failed to find reference implementation for '395/new' Layer with 'Convolution' Type on constant propagation`

Comment: @AddisonKlinke no didn't find a solution yet ! :(

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.bat on the latest OpenVINO Release (2021.4.1) and I did not see any issues. Could you try on the latest release and ensure your system meets the minimum [system requirements](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/system-requirements.html)?

**Processors**

6th to 11th generation Intel® Core™ processors

1st to 3rd generation of Intel® Xeon® Scalable processors

```
###############|| Run Inference Engine classification sample ||###############


Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
    1 file(s) copied.
classification_sample_async.exe -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021\deployment_tools\demo\car.png" -m "C:\Users\jgespino\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\ir\public\squeezenet1.1\FP16\squeezenet1.1.xml" -d CPU
[ INFO ] InferenceEngine:
    IE version ......... 2021.4.1
    Build ........... 2021.4.1-3926-14e67d86634-releases/2021/4
[ INFO ] Parsing input parameters
[ INFO ] Files were added: 1
[ INFO ]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021\deployment_tools\demo\car.png
[ INFO ] Loading Inference Engine
[ INFO ] Device info:
    CPU
    MKLDNNPlugin version ......... 2021.4.1
    Build ........... 2021.4.1-3926-14e67d86634-releases/2021/4

[ INFO ] Loading network files:
[ INFO ]     C:\Users\jgespino\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\ir\public\squeezenet1.1\FP16\squeezenet1.1.xml
[ INFO ] Preparing input blobs
[ WARNING ] Image is resized from (787, 259) to (227, 227)
[ INFO ] Batch size is 1
[ INFO ] Loading model to the device
[ INFO ] Create infer request
[ INFO ] Start inference (10 asynchronous executions)
[ INFO ] Completed 1 async request execution
[ INFO ] Completed 2 async request execution
[ INFO ] Completed 3 async request execution
[ INFO ] Completed 4 async request execution
[ INFO ] Completed 5 async request execution
[ INFO ] Completed 6 async request execution
[ INFO ] Completed 7 async request execution
[ INFO ] Completed 8 async request execution
[ INFO ] Completed 9 async request execution
[ INFO ] Completed 10 async request execution
[ INFO ] Processing output blobs

Top 10 results:

Image C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021\deployment_tools\demo\car.png

classid probability label
------- ----------- -----
817     0.6853030   sports car, sport car
479     0.1835197   car wheel
511     0.0917197   convertible
436     0.0200694   beach wagon, station wagon, wagon, estate car, beach waggon,         station waggon, waggon
751     0.0069604   racer, race car, racing car
656     0.0044177   minivan
717     0.0024739   pickup, pickup truck
581     0.0017788   grille, radiator grille
468     0.0013083   cab, hack, taxi, taxicab
661     0.0007443   Model T

[ INFO ] Execution successful

[ INFO ] This sample is an API example, for any performance measurements please use the dedicated benchmark_app tool

###############|| Classification demo completed successfully ||###############
```